# visibilityOf(WebElement) is not working in PageFactory for

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have written following method to know  whether an element exists or not in UI.

My framework is based on PageFactory using Selenium and Java. I am performing selenium actions (click, sendKeys etc.) by waiting until element is displayed using explict wait.

But the below function is not working while I use PageFactory. Can someone please let me know how I can proceed?

```
public boolean isElementPresentInDom(WebElement element, int timeout) {
    try {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(timeout));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
        return true;
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        return false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new FrameworkException("Exception while checking presence of element in 
              DOM " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Edited:- These waits are not working only for proxy element. For following example webelement.

Proxy element for: DefaultElementLocator 'By.xpath: .//div[@class='loader']//ancestor::div[contains(@class, 'ui-main active')]//div[normalize-space(text())='Loading']'

I do not know how PageFactory decides proxy element. Some say that the elements that are initialized through PageFactory are proxy element. This is untrue. I have printed few webelements that are initialized using PageFactory. For loading spinner it is showing as proxy element, for other it is printing as
[[ChromeDriver: chrome on WINDOWS (8a59f4584ddb623ce8d372ce71f8d2f1)] -> xpath: //input[text()='data']//ancestor::a[contains(@class,'button')]]

Comment: Add try-catch for the findelement method also.

Comment: What is the need of finding element in PageFactory?

Comment: oooh, you are using the @FindBy method, if this method you are taking it from the utility/helper class, then you can wrap it with the try-catch method for the FindBy element.